# Alchemy API returning "not found" on endpoints in docs

Tags: alchemy

I have the following code:

```py
import requests

url = "https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/<REDACTED_API_KEY>/findContractDeployer"

payload = {"contractAddress": "0x514910771AF9Ca656af840dff83E8264EcF986CA"}
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

However, I keep getting "Not Found" to return. But this is identical to what is in the [Alchemy docs.](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/sdk-findcontractdeployer)

This is happening on a few different endpoints, and I get the same error running this as a curl command. What is going on?

Comment: When I look at their implementation of the js SDK, they don't send request to the `findContractDeployer` endpoint but used only `eth_getCode` to perform binary search for the deployment tx (where the code of that address from 0x0 becomes something else) : https://github.com/alchemyplatform/alchemy-sdk-js/blob/71142b5385954823c65cdba8892d17381078a25b/src/api/core-namespace.ts#L364-L393. Probably that endpoint doesn't work

Comment: ah I see, so the SDK is not actually necessarily hitting a specific endpoint of the alchemy API.